# How can I extract only hours and minutes in the format HH:MM from a HH:MM:SS time string?

Tags: php, string, date, time

I'm getting the time in this format:

```
0:18:32
```

If I do `var_dump()` I get:

```
string '0:18:32:���' (length=11)
```

The time is saved in  my DB as `18:32:00`.

I want to get `HH:MM` out of this and I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
$AdmissionTime = strftime("%H:%M" ,$patient['TIME_UNIT_ADM'] );
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well from where do you got this time from `string '0:18:32:���' (length=11)` ?

Comment: strftime takes a unix timestamp as a parameter, is that what $patient['TIME_UNIT_ADM'] is?

Comment: No it comes from a 4th Dimension DB. Time is stored as `HH:MM:SS` there. The chars baffles me as-well.

Comment: Check if those chars are in DB actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you have some weird characters at the end of your date string, you could just use [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) combined with [`vprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php) to only grab hours and minutes from it and display it in your desired format:

```
$str = "0:18:32:���";
vprintf("%02d:%02d", sscanf($str, "%d:%d"));
```

output:

```
00:18
```

Comment: Oaky thanks, I want `18:32` so i suppose `vprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", sscanf($str, "%d:%d:%d")); could work, then only strip up to the first `:`. A bit of a hack, but i suppose it will work

Comment: @morne If you want to grab `18:32` just change it to: `vprintf("%02d:%02d", array_slice(sscanf($str, "%d:%d:%d"), 1));`